# PHP как убрать нули только с левой стороны?

Tags: php

Есть числа:

```
0.00036008
0.00369761
0.00002406
0.00040000
0.00140000
1.04020420
5.00000001
```

Чего я хочу достичь:

```
36008
369761
2406
40000
140000
104020420
500000001
```

Подскажите, не знаю как это сделать
Если делать так, убираются все нули:

```
$chislo = 0.00036008
$chislo = str_replace('0.','',$chislo);
$chislo = str_replace('0','',$chislo);
print_r($chislo); //368
```

Сработа этот код.
Ответ:

```
$chislo = 0.00036008
 ltrim((string)$chislo, ‘0.’)? 
 ltrim((string)$chislo, ‘0’)? 
 print_r($chislo);
```

Comment: Умножить число на 100000000?

Comment: При умножении(0.00036008 * 100000000) получается 0.0003600836008

Comment: Не лучше в по циклу прогоните строку, сравнивая символы если 0 убираем и т.д.

Comment: Законы математики отменили?

Comment: ltrim((string)$chislo, ‘0.’)?

Comment: ltrim((string)$chislo, ‘0.’) сработало